# how django related_name used with the special keyword /

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-templates, django-views

I have three Model classes, **Product, ShoppingCart, ShoppingCartItem**

In shoppingCartItem class the product field connect with Product class and used the related_name='+', but in ShoppingCart class in the sub_total() call the "item.product.get_price()".
item is the related_query_name but the I have an issue with the ***.get_price() function.***

```
from django.utils import timezone
from django.db import models

class Product(models.Model):
    DISCOUNT_RATE = 0.10

    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField()
    price = models.FloatField()
    sale_start = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    sale_end = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    photo = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True, default=None, upload_to='products')

    def is_on_sale(self):
        now = timezone.now()
        if self.sale_start:
            if self.sale_end:
                return self.sale_start <= now <= self.sale_end
            return self.sale_start <= now
        return False

    def get_rounded_price(self):
        return round(self.price, 2)

    def current_price(self):
        if self.is_on_sale():
            discounted_price = self.price * (1 - self.DISCOUNT_RATE)
            return round(discounted_price, 2)
        return self.get_rounded_price()


class ShoppingCart(models.Model):
    TAX_RATE = 0.13

    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def subtotal(self):
        amount = 0.0
        for item in self.shopping_cart_items:
            amount += item.quantity * **item.product.get_price()
        return round(amount, 2)**

    def taxes(self):
        return round(self.TAX_RATE * self.subtotal(), 2)

    def total(self):
        return round(self.subtotal() * self.taxes(), 2)


class ShoppingCartItem(models.Model):
    shopping_cart = models.ForeignKey(ShoppingCart, related_name='items', related_query_name='item', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, **related_name='+'**, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()

    def total(self):
        return round(self.quantity * self.product.current_price())
```

Comment: Exactly what is the issue?

Comment: item.product.get_price()
        return round(amount, 2) issue with the get_price() function which is not defined in the product class but used in shoppingcart  class